# Print the total number of digits in certain positions of my list

Tags: python, list, tuples

```
import random

X = []

 for i in range(100):

    X.append(random.randint(-25,25))

print(X)
```

I want to print the number of digits that the 5th and 100th element of the list have.

Note: For instance, the number 1 contains one digit, the number 10 contains two digits. we consider that the number -2 contains one digit.

```
numberOfDigits = [len(i) for i in X[5,10]]

print(numberOfDigits)


----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-6de47a5248e0> in <module>
----> 1 numberOfDigits = [len(i) for i in X[5,10]]

      2 print(numberOfDigits)

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Comment: Please format your code as code, and provide a brief description on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please specify what you're trying to do and then upload your code sample.

Comment: You can't find the length of an integer value directly. You have to convert it to string and then you can find the length like this `len(str(i))`. And you can retrieve the value non-continous indices of elements of the list by writing seperately like `X[5]` and `X[10]`

Comment: Not sure I understood. My code keeps craking...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the length of 5th and 10th element of list, this is the way to do it, as mentioned by @Dinesh

```
fifth_digits = len(str(X[5]))
hundredth_digits = len(str(X[99]))   #If you are running loop till 100
```